# A correct way to save html to database and then display it on the page in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, encoding, ckeditor, wysiwyg

The question is all about encoding.

Currently, I have the following pipeline for html that user produces.

A user is presented with a ckeditor WYSIWYG editor on the page via AngularJS wrapper.

User inputs some text, formats it, this results in html generated in DOM.
Then I use Angular to POST ckeditors contents to ASP.NET MVC Endpoint, where content is automatically wrapped into a string parameter of the action.

That generated string is assigned to a string property of Entity Framework Entity object and saved via DbContext to a database.

Then, to display it, I retrieve entity from Db via DbContext, get that html in string variable in controller code, where I assign it to a View Model for Razor View.

During Razor rendering the string property of the model with html in it is put on the page via @Html.Raw(Model.HtmlMarkupPropery) helper call.

Sometimes I see diamonds with question marks instead of cyrillic (or any two byte) characters, therefore I suspect some encoding problems along the way.

Please let me know where I am not Encoding/Decoding correctly (if any).

Comment: You sometimes see diamonds? Or every time

Comment: Every time. IIS sends http responses in stream to a client. Stream is written to via several buffers. If the UTF-8 2-byte character happened to be split by buffers (one byte in one buffer, second byte in the next buffer), diamond will appear on the same page in this split-spot every consequent request to that page. Maybe IIS problem, but I want to know which is the correct way to process UTF-8 endoded html input from js and then display it via razor.

Comment: Add extra checking in your buffers to make sure it doesn't get split on 2-byte character?

Comment: Buffers are inside IIS 8 Web Server code. Not my ASP.NET C# code.

Comment: How are you sure that's what's happening?

Comment: I've enabled FailedRequestTracing from successful requests in IIS. With that I was able to see an entire pipeline of a request, including buffers contents. Investigating contents lead me to understanding a rules, by which problematic rhombuses occur.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where the data is truncated after an ampersand (&). I.E. any data after an & in the WYSIWYG HTML string is not even submitted to the database. Could this be that the HTML string just needs to be HTML encoded before submitting it?